# Set text for textview that is in a fragment from another fragments onClick event

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm new here so please bear with me.

I am trying to set text in a textview from the onClick method of a fragment but I keep getting this error:

> Non-static field 'textView' cannot be referenced from a static context

Everything I've tried hasn't worked so I'm asking for help.

I have this fragment that has a button that I want to set the text of a textView:

**PullFragment.java**

```
public class PullFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

public PullFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pull, container, false);

    //The button
    ImageButton toolbarButtonPull;
    toolbarButtonPull = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbarButtonPull);
    toolbarButtonPull.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick (View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.toolbarButtonPull:
            // Here is the button onClick event
            break;
    }
}
}
```

This is the other fragment that has the textView:

**PlaceholderFragment.java**

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

public TextView textView;

public PlaceholderFragment() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_pull, container, false);
    // Here is the textView I want to change
    textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

I have tried the following in the onClick event:

```
PlaceholderFragment.textView.setText("Test");

//Or trying to call public void Test which just does "textView.setText("Text");"

PlaceholderFragment.Test();
```

> Non-static field 'textView' cannot be referenced from a static context

```
PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
placeholderFragment.textView.setText("Text");

//Or trying to call public void Test which just does "textView.setText("Text");"

PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
placeholderFragment.Test();
```

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Maybe I'm missing something simple but I haven't made any progress on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google suggests using interfaces for communication between fragments, see documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Also, I think [this](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activity-using-viewmodel-ca733233a51c) is a good tutorial, using activity's shared ViewModel for transferring data between fragments.

Answer (score -1):

**The first problem**:

> I have tried the following in the onClick event:
>
> ```
> PlaceholderFragment.textView.setText("Test");
>
> //Or trying to call public void Test which just does "textView.setText("Text");"
>
> PlaceholderFragment.Test();
> ```
>
> > Non-static field 'textView' cannot be referenced from a static context

The error `Non-static field 'textView' cannot be referenced from a static context` is to be expected because you can't access a variable or a method of a class without instantiating the object. Except if you make it a static variable or a static method. So, you need to make them static like this:

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

  public static TextView textView;

  public PlaceholderFragment() {}

  ...

  public static void test() {
    ...
  }
}
```

**The second problem**:

> ```
> PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();  
> placeholderFragment.textView.setText("Text");
>
> //Or trying to call public void Test which just does "textView.setText("Text");"
>
> PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();  
> placeholderFragment.Test();
> ```
>
> > Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
> >     object reference

The error:
`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference` is also to be expected. It is because when you're calling the following:

```
PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();    
placeholderFragment.textView.setText("Text");
```

the `placeholderFragment` is not yet fully instantiated. It's because the Fragment creation is not a synchronous process. So, when you're calling the `placeholderFragment.textView.setText("Text");` the textView is not yet created and binded to the fragment. You need to set the text via arguments or wait until the fragment is fully created.